# Rsync progress waits a long time after finish

Tags: rsync, cache, progress-information

When I am running `rsync` to copy big file (within directory on local hard drive)

```
+ rsync -P bigfile1.img bigfile2.img
bigfile1.img
  6,512,705,536 100%  413.76MB/s    0:00:15 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
```

it first shows progress up to 100% and then waits approximately the same time without any change and only then exits.

This probably due to some caching.

Can I display real progress?

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can try.

1. try --debug=all or -v verbose.
2. while waiting to get the prompt back try    #sstrace -ttT

based on the transfer rate shown, file size and time it took (0.15) looks good.  validate that time includes the wait time.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Try `rsync --outbuf=L` to get realtime progress.

It could be output buffering, which is mentioned in rsync's `man` pages at the `--bwlimit` switch for limiting the bandwidth:

> --bwlimit=RATE
>
> (...)
>
> Due to the internal buffering of data, the --progress option may not be an accurate reflection on how  fast  the
> data  is  being  sent.   This  is  because some files can show up as being rapidly sent when the data is quickly
> buffered, while other can show up as very slow when the flushing of the output buffer occurs.  This may be fixed
> in a future version.

The `--outbuf` switch:

> --outbuf=MODE
> This sets the output buffering mode.  The mode can be None (aka Unbuffered), Line, or Block (aka Full).  You may
> specify as little as a single letter for the mode, and use upper or lower case.
> The main use of this option is to change Full buffering to **Line buffering when rsync's output is going to a file**
> or pipe.

Comment: This didn't work for me